# How to make Qt WebView display websites like chrome?

Tags: qt, webkit

In Qt Creator, the webview displays websites just like IE would. How can I make it display using webkit like Chrome does?

Comment: dont think so, its the internal browser from QT and they decided to stick to IE (I believe its more... "the plain easy website parsing without fancy css" stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesnt use the webkit engine but your Qt Webview does just like the Google Chrome browser. So the difference might be in the webkit version your Qt Webview is using. Try reading about webkit and updating your qt sdk with the latest version. You can also try and toggle webview attributes like javascript and developer tools to check if the problem is with your code or the webview.

Comment: I went to my website using the webview, it displays it just like IE, the music player doesn't work and stuff. I have the most recent version of QT, or at least a VERY recent version ~ a couple weeks. I'll try to toggle javascript.

Comment: I just tested javascript, it uses the webview just like safari.

Comment: I really wish it was chrome instead -.-